# Getting <span> attribute values

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, attributes

I have this big chunk of html code and I want to extract every value of an attribute of span called "data-content"

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("C:\\Users\\stasiek\\Desktop\\Atom-PYTHON\\Python-Udemy\\web-scraping\\strona.html") as raw_resuls:
    results = BeautifulSoup(raw_resuls, "html.parser")

for element in results.find_all("span"):
        print(element['data-content'])
```

This code only returns the value of the first "data-content" there is (just a single word) in this file and then throws an error:

```
 File "niemiecki.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(element['data-content'])
  File "C:\Users\stasiek\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1406, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'data-content'
```

Any ideas what im doing wrong?

Comment: It would seem that not all of your spans have a data-content attribute.

Comment: Are you sure every `span` has the attribute `data-content`?

Comment: That propably was the issue, I didnt know how to solve it though. Now I do thanks to Justin so the problem is solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select only those with said attribute, e.g.,

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from io import BytesIO

data = b'''\
<body>
<span data-content="foo">1</span>
<span>2</span>
<span data-content="bar">3</span>
<span>4</span>
<span>5</span>
</body>
'''

f = BytesIO(data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')
for span in soup.select('span[data-content]'):
    print(span['data-content'])
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thank you very much!

Comment: You can always [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).